# How to merge git branches when you restructured the code in the main branch

Tags: android, git, github

I have been working on a project with a small team from my university. It's an application that started with a simple main page alone, then we all branched off to create different components.

One of us turned the main page into a cards page to leaf through profiles,
the other turned the main page into a login page,
the other implemented navigation between pages on the main page,
and I made new files in which to implement said code.
All on different branches. I merged my part with the master branch first.

How do we merge these branches? For each of these jobs, I need the full change history that they initially did on the main page, but each applied to/merged onto a different file in the current master branch.
As it is, git only wants to update the main file. Is copy/pasting the code from the other branches onto the correct files in main the only way?

Answer (score 1):

The two main ways to bring in the changes from the various feature branches into the `master` branch are merging and rebasing.  Given that you want to preserve the history of work done in each feature branch, merging is not desirable, because the resulting `master` branch will just have one merge commit representing all the work from each feature branch.  The actual commits from each feature branch will not directly appear in `master`.

One way to preserve history in this case would be to use rebasing instead.  In this approach, each feature branch would rebase on the latest `master`.  After doing this, the feature can then fast-forward `master` will all commits done in the feature.  If you are using something like GitHub or Bitbucket, here is what the workflow might look like:

```
# from feature
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push --force origin feature
```

Then, you would create a pull request going back to `master`.  Upon completing that pull request, the entire history of the feature branch would be played on top of `master`.

Here is a general branch diagram showing how rebasing works.  It assumes that the feature branch has made 2 new commits since branching off `master`.  Also, it assumes that two new commits from some other feature branch have been pushed to `master` since the first feature was branched.  Before rebasing looks like this:

```
master:  A -- B -- C
          \
feature:   D -- E
```

After rebasing feature on `master`, the diagram looks like this:

```
master:  A -- B -- C
                    \
feature:             D' -- E'
```

That is, now feature's history looks like the author just came in on top of the latest `master` and did all his work.  The resulting pull request is simply an instruction to lay down a bunch of new commits on the latest `master`, and all history of work should be preserved.

Comment: How would I make those changes affect a file other than the main file that I mentioned?

Comment: I don't understand your question.